# Basic attacks on McEliece; finding S and P

Tags: public-key, cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, mceliece, attack

Take a [McEliece cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem) with public generator matrix $G' = S G P$ where $G$ is a generator of a secret code with known fast decoding (not necessarily a Goppa code over $\mathbb{F}_2$), $S$ is random & non-singular and $P$ is a permutation.

Let's say an attacker Eve has a way to find $G$ from $G'$ but not $S$ or $P$. How would Eve now continue the attack on a encrypted codeword $c = mSGP+e$?

There are ways to find $P$, if you know $SG$: [Support splitting algorithm](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/30/37/PDF/RR-3637.pdf), but I don't see how Eve can continue without $S$.

---

*Clarification / Example / Thoughts from previous answers*

One of the problems is, that $P$ changes the code enough already, that it will be hard to decode. This is an example over $\mathbb{F}_2$

$G:=\left( \begin{eqnarray} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{eqnarray} \right)$ generates the code
$\mathcal{C} = \mathbb{F}_2^2G= \left\{ (0,0,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0,1),(0,0,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1,0) \right\}$.
Take the permutation that switches the 2nd and 3rd component
$P = (23)$.

The generator $GP$ now generates the code
$\mathcal{C}P = \left\{ (0,0,0,0,0),(1,0,1,0,1),(0,1,0,1,1),(1,1,1,1,0) \right\}$.

Take a codeword in $\mathcal{C}P$:
$c = (1,0,1,0,1) \in \mathcal{C}P$ and an error vector $e=(1,0,0,0,0)$.

$y=c+e=(0,0,1,0,1)$ has distance 1 to a codeword in $\mathcal{C}P$; so for someone who knows $P$ it could be translated into a codeword in $\mathcal{C}$ and decoded with $G$.

$y$ also has a distance of 1 to a codeword in $\mathcal{C}$, but to the wrong one; so simple decoding does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated problem is discussed in [this](http://www.santafe.edu/media/workingpapers/11-06-021.pdf) paper, called the *Scrambler-Permutation Problem*.

Answer (score 0):

After another good read through the current research papers [[1](http://cr.yp.to/codes/wild-20100721.pdf), [2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/112.pdf), [3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6458)] I'm not so sure anymore that the above stated problem does indeed have a solution, yet. I think it heavily depends on the chosen code $G$ whether it is possible to break the system; and all system breaking algorithms gave $S$ as well (or their equivalent in the Niederreiter cryptosstem).

I now do not think it is possible to retrieve $S$ given $G$ alone.