# Decrypting McEliece if security assumptions fail

Tags: coding-theory, mceliece, niederreiter

**1. G known - how to decrypt**
Referring to this question: [Basic attacks on McEliece; finding S and P](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17708/basic-attacks-on-mceliece-finding-s-and-p) (nobody answered)

Take a McEliece cryptosystem with public generator matrix $G′=SGP$ where $G$ is a generator matrix of a secret code with known fast decoding (not necessarily a Goppa code over $\mathbb F_2$), $S$ is random & non-singular and $P$
is a permutation.

Let's say an attacker Eve has a way to find $G$
from $G′$ but not $S$ or $P$.

How would Eve now continue the attack on a encrypted codeword $c=mSGP+e$?

**2. How can an attacker get $m$ if an oracle tells him the error $e$?**

So the attacker has the received garbled codeword $c = mG' + e = mSGP + e$ and knows $e$.
how can he calculate $m$

a) for one special garbled codeword $c$?

b) for every new garbled codeword $c$ without solving a system of equations every time?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you know $G$ and $G'$ you can recover typically recover $P$ from the [support splitting algorithm](https://inria.hal.science/inria-00073037/document). Note that the support-splitting algorithm is independent of the bases used to represent the two equivalent codes. Once you have $P$ one can compute $G''=GP$ and we can recover $S$ is we can solve $G'=SG''$. To do this we just find a subset of $\mathrm{rank}(G)$ columns of $G''$ of full rank so that if we write $C$ and $C''$ for the submatrices of $G$ and $G''$ formed by the corresponding columns then $C=SC''$ and $S=CC''^{-1}$.
2. a) Again, find a full rank subset of $\mathrm{rank}(G')$ columns, write $C'$ for the corresponding submatrix of $G'$ and $\mathbf x$ for the corresponding entries of $c-e$ and compute $C'^{-1}$. We then have $\mathbf x=mC'$ and so $m=\mathbf xC'^{-1}$. b) Note that the calculation of $C'^{-1}$ is one-time work, so for multiple messages our work is just the evaluation of a set of linear equations rather than their solution and in fact cheaper than the encryption process).

Answer (score -1):

2.a) there you can just solve the systems of equations
2.b) I think thats not possible

1 you could simply try out all possibilities for P - there are not so many ones, then calculate the corresponding S and voila

Comment: McEliece systems have $n$ columns where $n$ is typically in the thousands. There are $n!$ possible choices of $P$ which is not small.